# C# Winform freeze when using background worker

Tags: c#

Below is my coding:

```
Form2 msgForm;
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    //bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

    msgForm = new Form2();

    try
    {
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(comboBox15.Text);

        msgForm.ShowDialog();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string PrtAdd = e.Argument.ToString();

    uploadlogo(PrtAdd);
   // uploadlogo(PrtAdd) is the coding that transmit serial protocol and will last around 2 minutes to finish.        
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    msgForm.Close();
}
```

My coding is for running a backgroundworker when I click the button because clicking the button will transmit the protocols and it takes around 2 minutes.

During this 2 minutes, it will show "Please wait" in form2.

The problem is when I run this coding and click the button to run the background worker, my winform UI freeze. Is there a way not to freeze the UI?

Comment: In your real code, the bw.ProgressChanged event assignment is not commented, right?

Comment: Yes Hans Passant, it is commented because it is not use. Is it related to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does it freeze because you show a dialog (`msgForm.ShowDialog`)?

I do think so - try only `Show`